# Set breakpoints with CMake command for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, cmake

I generate a visual studio project with CMake.

Is it possible to set breakpoints via a CMake command, during or after project generation?

This would be great for a few assert calls that I always break on.

If it's possible to add breakpoints via a command line call, that would help too.

Thanks!

(XCode or Eclipse would help too)

Comment: I almost had this working from the command line using devenv /Command commands to open a specific line in a file and toggle break point. unfortunately it opens a bunch of windows in the process, and never worked right. I'm 99% sure I can do it with a console .NET app and the Visual Studio EnvDTE interface. If I find time, I'll built it and share it.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, it's not possible. Setting breakpoints is about **running** a program, while CMake is for **building** it.

Comment: The technical reason here is that VS saves the information about breakpoints in the `.suo` file, which is not generated by CMake but by VS itself.